# Is there a way how to automatically select only features with a good correlation from a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with 50+ columns and would like to drop low-correlated features with respect to a target using a loop, so I don't need to drop them manually.

I've tried:

```
for feature in df:
        if df[feature].corr() < threshold: df.drop(feature, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

...which obviuosly does not work.
I'm quite new to Python.

Advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the target is in `df['y']`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': range(500),
    'b': np.random.randint(0, 500, 500),
    'c': range(500),
    'd': np.random.randint(0, 500, 500),
    'y': range(500)})

threshold = 0.5
for feature in [c for c in df.columns if c != 'y']:
    if abs(df[feature].corr(df['y'])) < threshold:
        del df[feature]

df.head()
```

Output:

```
   a  c  y
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
```

Comment: Updated the loop to exclude `y` column itself -- that correlation is obviously 1

Comment: Works great! Thank you.